# Eigenvector of A by $A^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization, symmetric-matrices

Let $A$ be a real symmetric matrix. Assume $A^{2}v=\lambda Av$ , can we somehow deduce $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with $\lambda$ as its corresponding eigenvalue? i.e $Av=\lambda v$.
Thanks

Edit:
Also assume $\lambda \ne 0$ and we do not know if it is singular or nonsingular.

Comment: If $A$ is nonsingular, yes.

Comment: Let $A$ be the matrix $$A=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}\ .$$ What is $A^2$?

Comment: @dan_fulea But your $A$ is not symmetric

Comment: If it is not whether $A$ is singular, then the answer is no. As a counterexample, take
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}, \quad v = \pmatrix{1\\1}, \quad \lambda = 1.
$$

Answer (score 3):

Take $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\lambda = 2$. Then $A^2 = \lambda A$ so $v$ is arbitrary and not necessarily an eigenvector (e.g., $v = (1,2)^T)$.

However, you are guaranteed that either $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, or $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$. Proof: if $Av = 0$, $v$ is an eigenvector but $\lambda$ is arbitrary. If $Av \ne 0$, then $A(Av) = \lambda(Av)$ so $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ with eigenvector $Av$, as with the above counterexample.

It is true if $A$ is invertible as noted in the comments.